# Print unicode in ESCPOS_NET

Tags: c#, .net

I need to print a Unicode Vietnamese.
and my Code:

```
string text = "Phiếu Tính Tiền";
            var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1258");
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(text);
            string isoString = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1258").GetString(bytes);

            var e = new EPSON();
            printer.Write(ByteSplicer.Combine(
                e.Initialize(),
                e.CodePage(CodePage.WPC1258_VIETNAMESE),
                e.PrintLine(isoString)
                
            ));
```

but the result prints: `Phi? u Tính Ti? n`
why is that, can someone help me?
thanks.

Comment: You need to use a font that is compatible with Vietnamese.

Comment: My user "windows-1258" is encoding Vietnamese. But the result is not desired.

Comment: I believe the issue is the FONT that is being used and not the encoding.  Does the variable isoString contain the correct characters?  If so then it is not the encoding.

Comment: hi Jdweng, Thank you for the reply. I find resolve. although it is not a good solution. in Epson POS use TCVN for the Vietnamese language. ex e.printline( "Phiếu Tính Tiền" ). I writer: e.printline("PhiÕu TÝnh TiÒn"). Result print: Phiếu Tính Tiền.